# Why is SQL executing both lines

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, cursor, dynamic-sql

I'm running some dynamic SQL to look get me the names of a few tables.  Once I have these tables I'm running some code to insert the contents into a temporary table.  The issue I am having is that some tables have a column COL6.  In my temporary table I have a place holder for to hold all values from col1 to col6. But if it only has 5 I will just insert the 5 columns.

Unfortunately the code I have is running on both conditions. How can I correct this?

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM information_schema.COLUMNS 
WHERE  TABLE_NAME =     'MY_TABLE' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'COL6')
 BEGIN
  --if my table has col 6 I want this to run
INSERT INTO TMP_TABLE (COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4,COL5,COL6)
SELECT COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4,COL5,COL6 FROM MY_TABLE
END
 ELSE 
 BEGIN
   --If it does not I want this to run
INSERT INTO TMP_TABLE (COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4,COL5)
SELECT COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4, COL5 FROM MY_TABLE
END
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I gues my sql because he is using information_schema

Comment: as I understand from you ,, you want to insert depends how many columns you have , iif you have 3 columns , you want to insert 3 cols right ?

Comment: correct.....it is telling me col 6 does not exists.  but if col 6 is not there I don't want to run that insert I want to run the insert with 5 columns

Comment: MS sql server is what i'm using

Comment: This question would be remarkably improved if it included the *error message* that you've conveniently forgotten to mention anywhere, which is in fact not an indication that both lines are executing - that's your supposition based on the error message but is in fact not true.

Answer (score 2):

You're misinterpreting things. The code isn't *running* at all. You're getting a *compile* error when `COL6` doesn't exist. As an analogy, consider a C# function that first checks via reflection whether a class has a certain member function and then tries to directly invoke that function on a variable of that type - if the class doesn't *have* that function, you're going to get a compiler error.

So, instead, you have to avoid compiling code that relies on a particular metadata lookup until you've got the result of that lookup:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM information_schema.COLUMNS 
WHERE  TABLE_NAME =     'MY_TABLE' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'COL6')
BEGIN
  --if my table has col 6 I want this to run
   EXEC('INSERT INTO TMP_TABLE (COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4,COL5,COL6)
         SELECT COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4,COL5,COL6 FROM MY_TABLE')
END
ELSE 
BEGIN
   --If it does not I want this to run
    EXEC('INSERT INTO TMP_TABLE (COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4,COL5)
          SELECT COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4, COL5 FROM MY_TABLE')
END
```

(You probably don't have to similarly protect the `ELSE` part since it can compile either way, but I'd normally do it like this just for symmetry)

Answer (score 1):

Even if you only want to insert just 5 columns, you select 6. Select 5 columns in "else"  and it should be fine

Comment: give an example please

Comment: Unfortunately this is not happening ......I tided up my snippet an added comments